# Where are parameters in fortran shared libraries stored?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, nm

I'm trying to build a fortran shared library to be inserted into another code and am trying to understand what happens to module level parameters and where they are stored in the library.

A minimal example like this:

```
MODULE test
IMPLICIT NONE

public
integer,parameter :: my_x=1
integer :: my_y

contains

subroutine my_func(a)
    integer, intent(in) :: a

    my_y=my_x*a

end subroutine my_func

END MODULE
```

And making a shared library out of this:

```
gfortran -shared -fPIC testShared.f90 -o libtest.so
```

Then running

```
nm libtest.so
```

Outputs:

> 0000000000201018 B __bss_start
>
> 0000000000201018 b completed.6938
>
> ```
>              w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
> ```
>
> 00000000000005e0 t deregister_tm_clones
>
> 0000000000000670 t __do_global_dtors_aux
>
> 0000000000200de8 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
>
> 0000000000200df8 d __dso_handle
>
> 0000000000200e00 d _DYNAMIC
>
> 0000000000201018 D _edata
>
> 0000000000201020 B _end
>
> 00000000000006fc T _fini
>
> 00000000000006b0 t frame_dummy
>
> 0000000000200de0 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
>
> 0000000000000788 r **FRAME_END**
>
> 0000000000201000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
>
> ```
>              w __gmon_start__
> ```
>
> 0000000000000708 r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
>
> 0000000000000598 T _init
>
> ```
>              w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
>
>              w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
> ```
>
> 0000000000200df0 d **JCR_END**
>
> 0000000000200df0 d **JCR_LIST**
>
> ```
>              w _Jv_RegisterClasses
> ```
>
> 0000000000000620 t register_tm_clones
>
> 00000000000006e0 T __test_MOD_my_func
>
> 000000000020101c B __test_MOD_my_y
>
> 0000000000201018 d **TMC_END**

I've also tried:

```
gfortran -shared -fPIC -ggdb -O0 testShared.f90 -o libtest.so
```

To the same effect.

We can see that there is (suitable mangled with underscores) my_func and my_y but no my_x. I would assume the compiler must still store my_x in the library somewhere in case another function linked later wants to use it, even if its compiled out of the function my_func, but i can't tell where that might be.

So is my assumption wrong and my_x is gone or is it stored somehow and i'm just not using nm correctly to be able to see it?

Comment: You probably have a file called something like `test.mod`.  This will contain information about the named constant.

Comment: Thanks i do see it in the test.mod file. Though i'm still wondering if there is a way to do it from the shared library? It would be easier if i could just look in one place to see what is defined.

Comment: I was stumbling on this today myself... And you cannot BIND(C) a PARAMETER.

(I was using OS X and gfortran).